# Xamarin.Forms Android AOT support

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

does anyone know how to use AOT compilation instead of JIT for Xamarin.Forms Android project?
Im simply unhappy with the boot times of Android app while iOS starts like it should (since iOS is forced to use AOT).

Also in which file specifically should I enable XAMLC? Right now im doing it inside Android project and iOS project AssemblyInfo files.

Thanks!

Comment: It does not matter which file you place the assembly level XamlCompilation attribute in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the Release configuration `PropertyGroup` in your `Xamarin.Android`'s `.csproj` file, add a `AotAssemblies` element that is set to true, optionally add an `EnableLLVM` element.

Note: As this will increase the size of your APK, my advice would be to make sure that the Mono Linker is active in your release config ("Link all assemblies" would be ideal to remove as much unused IL are possibly before the AOT process takes place to help minimize the size of each native shared library)

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ~~~
    <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
    ~~~
</PropertyGroup>
```

> AotAssemblies – A boolean property that determines whether or not assemblies will be Ahead-of-Time compiled into native code and included in the .apk.
>
> EnableLLVM – A boolean property that determines whether or not LLVM will be used when Ahead-of-Time compiling assemblies into native code.

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process

Comment: For me with aot +llvm the xamarin app startup time is longer than with aot alone..